# Should I create a new repository when I need to change npm module name?

Tags: git, npm, npm-publish

I want to rename a npm module to have a different name, should I create (or fork) a new repository for this change and deprecate the old repo? 
Plus if we create/fork a new repo, should I reset the version back to initial (0.1.0) or keep the current version number?

Im not sure what's the best or common approach in this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a rule.

If it is just renaming I would  fork in order to be friendly with other persons that could have used the original repo.

Regarding the version, I would avoid duplicating versions (I.e: use greater versions than current) to reduce misunderstanding chances.

If it is a complete rewrite, use a new repo increasing major version.

Also note, that you should add a *deprecation* and *how to migrate* notes in original repo.

Comment: That's the approach Im taking.. Still I think there should be a standard or oficial recommendation on how to properly do this changes.